# Symfony PUT request doesn't update entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'am working on symfony REST API and currently i stopped at PUT request to edit data. I don't know where either search for bug.

My code look like this.

Controller.php

```
    /**
 * User update
 *
 * @Rest\Put("/users/{id}", name="user_update")
 * @Rest\View()
 * @param  Request $request
 * @param          $id
 * @param Users    $restUser
 *
 *
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function updateUserAction( Request $request, $id, Users $restUser )
{
    $results = [];

    $user = $this->em->getRepository( User::class )
                     ->find( $id )
    ;
    /**
     * Data to update user
     */
    if ( ! $user )
    {
        $results[ 'message' ] = sprintf( 'No users found with {%s} ID', $id );
        $results[ 'status' ] = 'failure';

        return View::create( $results );
    }
    $results[ 'beforeUpdate' ] = $user;
    $newData = $request->request->all();

    /**
     * Try to update
     */
    try
    {
        $form = $this->createForm( UserType::class, $user );
        $form->submit( $newData );
        if ( $form->isValid() )
        {
            $results[ 'status' ] = 'success';
            $results[ 'message' ] = 'Pomyślnie zaaktualizowsano użytkownika';

            $this->em->persist( $user );
            $this->em->flush();
        }
        $results[ 'errors' ] = $form->getErrors( FALSE, TRUE );
    }
    catch( \Exception $exception )
    {
        $results[ 'status' ] = 'failure';
        $results[ 'message' ] = 'Wystąpił błąd przy aktualizacji';
        $results[ 'message_exception' ] = $exception->getMessage();

    }
    /**
     * Get BODY of request
     */
    $results[ 'sentData' ] = $newData;


    return View::create($results);
}
```

And UserFormType.php

```
class UserType extends AbstractType implements FormTypeInterface{

public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
{
    $resolver->setDefaults( [
        'data_class'         => User::class,
        'allow_extra_fields' => TRUE,
        'csrf_protection'    => FALSE,
    ] );
}

}
```

Basic question is that I do everything ok? Im new to Symfony and try my best everytime i try to do something i think i get each available error.

Comment: a form does only update fields that are defined in it's `buildForm` method. Also your blatant misuse of the form suggests, you only want the validator (which you could dependency-inject). the "allow_extra_fields" only avoids the error message when a form gets data for different fields than it expects.

Comment: the related question on the right might give you some hints on how to do this, also consult the tutorials on forms and https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html for the final submit

Comment: @Jakumi, thanks for reply. I added to UserType.php method you mentioned ( here https://pastebin.com/zkJHteCp ). But now i noticed that data from request is null when i past them to $form->submit($newData). Any ideas what is wrong? $newData is from $request->request->all()

Comment: have you checked what is found in `$newData`? because I think that's probably the reason. I'm not sure what the `@Rest/Put` Annotation does. If it doesn't contribute to this, then you're probably on the wrong track: apparently "PUT" data isn't read into the `Request` as expected, but instead must be parsed by yourself, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858279/access-http-put-data-in-symfony2 and https://codereviewvideos.com/course/beginners-guide-back-end-json-api-front-end-2018/video/update-symfony-4-json-api-put (the second is for json though).

Comment: @Jakumi I figured out that i must send variables with exact naming system like i declared in formbuilder, for example i do form->add('firstName'), and in frontend i must sent data with camelCase naming sytem instead of snakecase (like i recieve from backend). I changed to $form->add('first_name') and it works. Don't know reason why it is done that. Thanks for help man

Comment: are you getting request data from controller?